# How to access Media Files across Android and Ubuntu while using dual-boot

Tags: dual-boot, files, sharing

I'm using dual-boot on my Nexus 4 with Android and Ubuntu OS. Is there an option to access the Media (Picture, Music, Video etc.) files stored on Mobile while boot in either OS? E.g. the stored music files on Android want to be accessed when boot in Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

On android you can access files of ubuntu foler in /data/user-data/phablet 
No way to access android folders from ubuntu yet.

Answer (score 0):

### Inside Ubuntu

You can achieve that using adb!

```
$ adb shell

# su - phablet
$ cd ~
$ sudo mkdir android 
$ sudo mount --bind /userdata/media/0 ~/android
$ sudo chmod 775 android
$ sudo chown phablet:phablet android
```

You could optionally create a shell script and execute it from a terminal - inside Ubuntu Touch.
Source: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2595752

Answer (score 0):

FYI,

I believe this can be achieved with the latest image. It worked for me.

Please read la7low's post [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/general/rom-ubuntu-touch-14-10-utopic-unico-t2324683/page160)

Thank you la7low!